# Meteor markdown not working as expected

Tags: meteor, markdown

I'm using meteor 1.1 and [the core markdown package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/markdown).
I have this sample code:

```
<template name="about">
    {{#markdown}}## About me
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud **exercitation ullamco** laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Link to my facebook: [facebook.com][1] [1]: http://facebook.com
    {{/markdown}}
</template>
```

the header (about me) is displayed properly as a header, but the rest of the content is displayed as simple text with no formatting.

It only works if i wrap each line with it's own `{{#markdown}}`, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 space indentation on the lines of text will put the line into a `<pre><code>` block.

What you want to do is not indent the content within the `{{#markdown}}` block.

Also reference-style link definitions need to be on their own line.

IE:

```
<template name="about">
{{#markdown}}
## About me
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud **exercitation ullamco** laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Link to my facebook: [facebook.com][1] 
[1]: http://facebook.com
{{/markdown}}
</template>
```